# Detect BOOL availability to support multiple iOS versions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean, backwards-compatibility

I am trying to find out how one can detect if an external BOOL is available so that I can support iOS 7 and 8. New in iOS 8 is a BOOL you can use to find out if Reduce Transparency is enabled, and I want to implement that check in an if statement, but this will crash on iOS 7 without first checking if the extern BOOL is available. I was surprised I could not find the answer from my web searches.

Here is the BOOl definition:

```
UIKIT_EXTERN BOOL UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled() NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

And the location I'm using it:

```
if (UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()) {
    NSLog(@"transparency is disabled");
}
```

Comment: @user3386109 Please do not check the OS version. There are much better solutions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please read the [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i).

What you need to do is check if the function `UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled` exists:

```
if (UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled != NULL) {
    // function exists, use it
    if (UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()) {
        NSLog(@"transparency is disabled");
    }
} else {
    // function doesn't exist, do something else
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the link to that document. Will be a good read.